# iPhone view loaded many times... but never unloaded?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, viewdidload, viewwillappear

My iPhone app is based on a common "utility template" like Apple's own Weather app.

I click on the info-button and it flips the screen around.  I click on my done button... and it flips back.  That part all seems to work ok.

I've placed NSLog() statements into each of 4 methods in my FlipSideViewController.m

```
viewDidLoad
viewWillAppear
viewDidUnload
viewWillDisappear
```

Shouldn't I see viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear being called when I flip TO my FlipSide.
And then see viewWillDisappear and viewDidUnload when I flip back?

Instead, I never see any viewDidUnload call.   But I DO see another viewDidLoad each time I flip TO my FlipSide.   It's that wrong?

Flipping back and forth, again and again, I would see:

```
viewDidLoad
viewWillAppear
viewWillDisappear

viewDidLoad
viewWillAppear
viewWillDisappear

viewDidLoad
viewWillAppear
viewWillDisappear
```

Doesn't that mean the view reloaded 3 times... but unloaded 0 times?
Shouldn't there be "matching" load/unload and appear/disappear methods happening here?

Comment: could you post the code for your flip effect ? i think you're not removing the view as you should.

Answer (score 7):

I thought so too at first, but apparently that's not the case.

The `viewDidUnload` method actually only gets called when the view controller gets a memory warning.

Nonetheless, the view will be released when the view controller is dealloc'd.

So, if you are releasing stuff like IB outlets in `viewDidUnload`, that's good, but you have to release them in `dealloc` as well, because `viewDidUnload` won't be called under normal circumstances (i.e., if you don't get memory warnings).

EDIT:
to release the `view` you just have to call `dealloc` on the super class `UIViewController` in your `dealloc`:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    // release your stuff, anything that you alloc or retain in your class

    // then call `dealloc` on the super class:
    [super dealloc];
}
```

in the `viewDidUnload` method you only have to release things that should get unloaded along with your view, usually things that you connected to `IBOutlet`s in interface builder.

```
- (void) viewDidUnload
{
    // if the property was declared with the "retain" keyword, you can
    // release it simply by setting it to nil like this:
    self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that reusing the *same* view controller (i.e., not releasing it) will result in calls to `viewDidUnload` more often, as the view controller itself will still be around, but the view may be off-screen (and the application can therefore unload it).

Comment: So what should my code look like inside viewDidUnload... and then again in dealloc... to release correctly?   (Also, won't I be releasing something that is already released?)